# How to dynamically store data in Multi Dimensional String Array

Tags: android, string, multidimensional-array

I have a problem related to storing data dynamically in `two Dimensional String Array`, `String[][]`.
I am dynamically storing data in the `String[i][j]` array. Here the first index's value is fixed i.e. `i=3`, but second index's value is different for all rows.

for example, I am getting values like this,

```
String arrElements[][] = {
        {"1"},
        {"abc", "xyz", "lkm", "pwd", "srt", "qwert"},
        {"1234", "3456"}
        };
```

I am getting values something like this. i.e there is only 1 value in the first row, any number of values in the second row and in the third row.

If I go like this,

```
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    String arrElements[][] = {};
    arrElements= new String[3][25];
            //What size should I define here.
    arrElements[0][0] = "Sahil";
    if (a == 0) { //Its just a logical representation of what I might be doing.
        // Store the value in second row
        arrElements[1][i] = a;
        i++;
    }
    if (a == 1) {
        // Store the value in third row
        arrElements[2][j] = a;
        j++;
    }
```

Now, I am setting these values in the `expandable list View`. If the number of values in any of the rows exceeds the size specified, it gives `ArrayOutOfBoundException`. and if the size is less than 25, it shows empty rows.

Now, I dont want to give hard coded size limit for the array indexes. Is there any better way to deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first remark: Are you sure a `String[][]` is the right data structure for what you want to achieve? There is a whole bunch of `Collection` classes that might be more suitable (`ArrayList` to name the most obvious).

If you really want to proceed with `String[][]` you can't define the length of the sub-arrays upfront but have to declare it per row:

```
String[][] foo = new String[4][];
foo[0] = new String[1];
foo[1] = new String[2];
// ....
```

But as I said you might be much happier with a nested `ArrayList` which resizes dynamically:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> foo = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
// Do the following for each row
foo.add(new ArrayList<String>>());
// Do the following to append data in row i
foo.get(i).add("new string");
// Do the following to retrieve column j in row i
foo.get(i).get(j);
```

Depending on what you actually want to store, other data structures might be much more suited.

Comment: First option sounds interesting. It would be good, if I could calculate the column count for each row and then define the length of sub-arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You can use whatever data structures you like.

In the `ExpandableListAdapter` that you pass to the view, just be sure you return correct values from `getGroupCount` and `getChildrenCount`. In `getGroup` and `getChild`, return the appropriate data from whatever backing structure you use (database cursor, list, list of lists, etc.).

One useful structure for this type of list is a `Map<GroupData, List<ChildData>>`. This might be as simple as a `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>` if the item text is the only data you have.

Comment: Yes, I was also thinking about it. Could ArrayList be a good alternate for it.?